# What is the lower bound for an algorithm that reconstructs a permutation?

Tags: algorithms, combinations

In this [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48089/134) on codegolf.SE, one has to reconstruct a permutation $p$ of a vector of length $n$ given only a function $P\colon\{0,1\}^n\mapsto\{0,1\}^n$ which applies $p$ to a vector of booleans, applying $P$ to the least amount of different arguments in the process.

My [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48091/134) to this challenge invokes $P$ on $\lceil\log_2n\rceil$ distinct inputs: It computes the binary representation of the numbers $0,1,\dots,n-1$, applies $P$ to vectors of the digits of equal value and then reassembles the results into numbers, yielding $p$.

I'd like to know if this solution is optimal with respect to the number of distinct arguments given to $P$. My approach to prove this is to apply the pidgeonhole principle: Invoking $P$ on less than $\lceil\log_2n\rceil$ inputs doesn't suffice to distinguish all possible $n!$ permutations but $\lceil\log_2n\rceil$ inputs will.

Let $m$ be the highest number of permutations you can distinguish from the observation of $P(v)$ for some $v$ using $\nmid$ for “does not divide” and $[\dots]$ as Iverson brackets:

$$m=\max_k{n\choose k}={n\choose{n+[2\nmid n]\over2}}$$

then I think what I want to show is

$$m^{\lceil\log_2n\rceil-1}<n!\le m^{\lceil\log_2n\rceil}$$

I'd like to know if proving this statement is sufficient for showing that $\lceil\log_2n\rceil$ is a strong lower boundary on the number of distinct arguments to $P$ needed to identify $p$. I'd also like to know how to prove this statement; I have absolutely no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it would suffice if you could prove the first inequality with strictness, but this is probably not possible because you are using a universal $m$ so probably it's more like $M_{k-1} < n! \leq M_k$ where $M_k$ is the maximum number of possibilities you can represent with a COMBINATION of $k$ queries. Note the overall equivalent effective '$m$' you will use may decrease when you use this formulation.

Comment: I fixed a couple of typos. I'm sorry if that changes your answer.